# sql server uniqueidentifier comparison

Tags: sql-server, select, triggers, uniqueidentifier

I am writing a trigger and I have a problem with one select command which is supposed to compare uniqueidentifier. It returns null. How can I fix this

```
DECLARE @EmailTablePrimaryKey  uniqueidentifier
SELECT @PostSpecialityID=CategoryId  FROM PostCategoryRelations WHERE PostId = @EmailTablePrimaryKey
```

@EmailTablePrimaryKey and PostId are uniqueidentifier, if I put parameters staticaly like below, it works, but it doesnt work with parameter.

```
SELECT @PostSpecialityID=CategoryId  FROM PostCategoryRelations WHERE PostId = '7c5ec001-81a2-e211-95dc-842b2b07eeaf'
```

what do you think is the problem?

Comment: You haven't shown `@EmailTablePrimaryKey` being populated. But use of scalar variables in a trigger is usually a warning sign that the author thinks that `inserted` contains a single row (it doesn't, in general. It could contain 0, 1 or many rows)

Comment: @EmailTablePrimaryKey returns a single row. I am sure about that. It is populated via another select statement

Comment: what else can I use instead of scalar variables?

Comment: If you *have* to perform work as multiple steps, you could use temp tables or table variables. *ideally*, you find a way to express your intention as a single query, using `inserted` as one of the source tables.

Comment: may be if you post about what trigger should do and tables involved, you get a better answer suited exactly to your task